# How to write unit-tests for discord bot

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit.net, discord.net

I'm currently tried to write my first project with TDD and I've chosen a discord bot based on Discord.Net to do so.

But right off the start I face a problem regarding the abstract classes that Discord.Net uses.
My first tests should concern the CommandHandler (which I will later extract into it's Interface and Implementation part).

The first test should check that the command is ignored if the bot is the author of the command.
Therefore my `OnMessageReceivedAsync`-method will accept a `SocketMessage`, but this is an abstract class.

How should I go about this and write proper unit tests for an Discord.Net based discord bot?

UPDATE:
I even tried it with Moq and mocking an `IMessage`, but I can't setup the mock because pretty much all of the fields are readonly. So I can't set the `Author` with this either.

My mock try is as follows:

```csharp
using Discord;
using Moq;
using Xunit;

namespace Runa.DiscordBot.Infrastructure.Tests
{
    public class CommandHandlerTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void OnMessageReceivedAsync_IgnoresSelfAsCommandIssuer()
        {
            Mock mockMessage = new Mock<IMessage>()
                .Setup(msg => msg.Author = "bot");
        }
    }
}
```

But as stated above with this I get the access-error when I try to set the `msg.Author = "bot"`, because the `Author` field has no `set` accessor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Mock<IMessage> mockMessage = new Mock<IMessage>();

mockMessage.SetupGet(msg => msg.Author).Returns("bot");
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.